# How to access microsoft outlook services in ASP.net web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, windows-authentication, outlook-addin

I need to get Microsoft outlook details specially calendar & meetings of a person who invokes an ASP.Net web service via Windows authenticated page. Kindly assist how to connect Microsoft outlook calendar to ASP.Net Web Service.

Comment: What code do you have so far. Have you read the outlook web services SDK?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid nopes. Could you please provide me the link to start. Till now I have just created a web service that will get username from windows authentication HTTP challenge and send it to the database.

Comment: If I was to give you the link I would simply be going to Google to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any given Outlook user's data is not guaranteed to be accessible from a web service or web application.  If the user is using POP3 or IMAP account, their data will be stored locally on their PC and cannot be read without installing a custom client application to read their Outlook data and communicate back to your web server.

If they are using an Exchange Mailbox, then you can access that data from your web server via Exchange Web Services - but you'd need to authenticate with their password (or an AD token if you have that already in your web app).